# How to find duplicate value in column on SQL with unique data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**PROBLEM:** 
Need to find all instances of when data was replicated by the user. Each time the user clicked a button, it created a unique batch of the same data. I need to provide a result set to a group that includes all instances a batch was "duplicated" by the end user.

**SAMPLE DATA:**
Using Microsoft SQL on Microsoft SQL Server.

Date types: batch int
,date date
,reference int
,from_state varchar(2)
,to_state varchar(2)
,item int
,qty int

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| batch   | date        | reference | from_state | to_state | item        | qty |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 11122334455 | 2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 66622334455 | 1   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 77722334455 | 5   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 11122334455 | 2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 66622334455 | 1   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 77722334455 | 5   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3456781 | 2016-03-01  | 6854      |  MT        | CA       | 00112233111 | 2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3456781 | 2016-03-01  | 6854      |  MT        | CA       | 00112255111 | 1   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3456781 | 2016-03-01  | 6854      |  MT        | CA       | 33322334455 | 5   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**DESIRED RESULTS:**
I need all of the information shown to resolve the issue. I can do a count to find the duplicate records by from, to, item, and qty, but I am lost on how to tie it back to the batch and reference number.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| batch   | date        | reference | from_state | to_state | item        | qty |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 11122334455 | 2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 66622334455 | 1   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 77722334455 | 5   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 11122334455 | 2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 66622334455 | 1   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 77722334455 | 5   |
```

**ATTEMPTED CODE:**

```
SELECT from_state
,to_state
,item
,qty
,COUNT(*)
FROM #TEMP_duplicates
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
GROUP BY from_state
,to_state
,item
,qty
```

Comment: what is your rdbms SqlServer Postgres? what is your expected result? You say `I need to fix each batch` but dont say what mean that fix

Comment: I have edited the problem wording

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Still you need to tell us what is your desire result so we dont have to guess. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @CoffeeCoder are you trying to identify items entered in multiple batches, or multiple entries of an item on a single batch?

Comment: I'm trying to identify multiple batches that have the EXACT same from_state, to_state, item, and qty. Apologies, I am working my best to make my problem and goal as clear as possible. I appreciate all feedback I have been receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone contributing to helping me solve this problem.

--Throw result set into temp table #TEMP_baseresults

```
SELECT batch
,reference 
,from_state
,to_state
,item
,qty
INTO #TEMP_baseresults
FROM datasource
```

--Find all duplicates for SAME from_state, to_state, item, and qty

```
SELECT from_state
,to_state
,item
,qty
,count(*) as 'count'
INTO #TEMP_batchduplicates
FROM #TEMP_baseresults
GROUP BY from_state
,to_state
,item
,qty
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY from_state
,to_state
,item
,qty
```

--JOIN duplicate table on base table

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEMP_baseresults base
JOIN #TEMP_batchduplicates dup
ON dup.from_state = base.from_state
AND dup.to_state = base.to_state
AND dup.item = base.item
AND dup.qty = base.qty
ORDER BY base.from_state
,base.to_state
,base.item
```

RESULTS DISPLAYED:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| batch   | date        | reference | from_state | to_state | item        | qty | count |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 11122334455 | 2   | 2     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 66622334455 | 1   | 2     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1234567 | 2016-03-01  | 8213      |  MT        | CA       | 77722334455 | 5   | 2     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 11122334455 | 2   | 2     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 66622334455 | 1   | 2     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1239764 | 2016-03-01  | 8597      |  MT        | CA       | 77722334455 | 5   | 2     |
```

This filtered down my data set to ONLY show the identified duplicate records, and it additionally flagged how many times the data was potentially duplicated.

Comment: At a glance it appears that your solution only considers individual rows. My impression from your question was that you needed to compare the batches in total to make sure that you had a complete and identical duplicate. In the future it would greatly help us all to give us as much information as possible in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using SQL Server based on the temp table reference in your attempted query so I'll run with that.

This would handle a single duplicate. I'd have to know more about the data to argue how about how reliable it will be. It's probably good enough for something that will be manually verified. I'll see if I can think of something for more than one copy.

```
with T as (
    select
        batch,
        min("date") as dt,
        min(reference) as reference,
        min(from_state) as from_state,
        min(to_state) as to_state,
        min(item) as item_min, max(item) as item_max, sum(item) as item_sum,
        min(qty) as qty_min, max(qty) as qty_max, sum(qty) as qty_sum,
        count(*) as cnt
    from <yourdata>
    group by batch
)
select t1.batch
from T t1 inner join T t2
    on t2.batch > t1.batch and t2.reference <> t1.reference
        and t2.dt = t1.dt
        and t2.from_state = t1.from_state and t2.to_state = t1.to_state
        and t2.item_min = t1.item_min and t2.qty_min = t1.qty_min
        and t2.item_max = t1.item_max and t2.qty_max = t1.qty_max
        and t2.item_sum = t1.item_sum and t2.qty_sum = t1.qty_sum
        and t2.cnt = t1.cnt
group by t1.batch
```

I'm sure what type you're using for `item`. It's possible that you'll need a cast to get the `sum()` to work.

**EDIT** I think this one is more robust in handling multiples set of duplicates. Can't speak to performance though.

```
with T as (
    select
        batch,
        min("date") as dt,
        min(reference) as reference,
        min(from_state) as from_state,
        min(to_state) as to_state,
        min(item) as item_min, max(item) as item_max, sum(item) as item_sum,
        min(qty) as qty_min, max(qty) as qty_max, sum(qty) as qty_sum,
        count(*) as cnt
    from <yourdata>
    group by batch
),
pairs as (
    select t1.*, t2.batch as batch2
    from T t1 inner join T t2
        on t2.batch > t1.batch and t2.reference <> t1.reference
            and t2.dt = t1.dt
            and t2.from_state = t1.from_state and t2.to_state = t1.to_state
            and t2.item_min = t1.item_min and t2.qty_min = t1.qty_min
            and t2.item_max = t1.item_max and t2.qty_max = t1.qty_max
            and t2.item_sum = t1.item_sum and t2.qty_sum = t1.qty_sum
            and t2.cnt = t1.cnt
)
select distinct
    min(batch) over (
        partition by
            dt, from_state, to_state,
            item_min, item_max, item_sum, qty_min, qty_max, qty_sum, cnt
        ) as orig_batch,
    batch2 as dup_batch
from pairs
```

"Original" batch is the one with the lowest id.

Perhaps you'd want to continue this thought by matching up with the pre-aggregated rows. Append this to the CTEs from above:

```
...
, matches as (
    select p.batch, p.batch2
    from
        pairs p inner join
        <yourdata> d1 on d1.batch = p.batch full outer join
        <yourdata> d2 on d2.batch = p.batch2
            and d2.dt = d1.dt
            and d2.from_state = d1.from_state and d2.to_state = d1.to_state
            and d2.item = d1.item and d2.qty = d1.qty
    group by p.batch, p.batch2
    having
            count(d1.dt) = count(*) and count(d2.dt) = count(*)
        and count(d1.from_state) = count(*) and count(d2.from_state) = count(*)
        and count(d1.to_state) = count(*) and count(d2.to_state) = count(*)
        and count(d1.item) = count(*) and count(d2.item) = count(*)
        and count(d1.qty) = count(*) and count(d2.item) = count(*)
)
select distinct
    min(batch) over (
        partition by
            dt, from_state, to_state,
            item_min, item_max, item_sum, qty_min, qty_max, qty_sum, cnt
        ) as orig_batch,
    batch2 as dup_batch
from pairs p inner join matches m on m.batch = p.batch and m.batch2 = p.batch2
```